# UIAlertView turn off auto dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, dismiss

when clicked button "ok" alert automatically closes, How to prevent it

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                    message:@"Message" 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

i want clicked button "OK" and not dismiss alert ..if(logics){ not dismis } else { dismiss alert }

thanx

Comment: Try something like https://github.com/regexident/DLAlertView which allows you to use delegates or blocks to respond to behavior.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The solution in the duplicate linked post subclasses `UIAlertView`. Bear in mind that `UIAlertView` is now deprecated in iOS 8 and replaced by `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create your own UI component if you want that behavior. `UIAlertView` is designed to display some basic information and give you some number of button options that once clicked, close the alert view.